# SIGACTION Structure

Tags: c, linux, sigaction

I have built a function (based in a example) that allows me to ignore the signal `SIGINT`. That function counts the times that the user press `CONTROL + C` (the interruption `SIGINT`). The function is the following one

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sig_atomic_t sigint_count = 0;

void handler (int signal_number)
{
    ++sigint_count;
    printf ("SIGINT was raised %d times\n", sigint_count);
}

int main ()
{
    struct sigaction sa; //Declaração da estrutura sigaction
    memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));//Libertação da memória usada
    sa.sa_handler = &handler;
    sigaction (SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is about this line of code

```
 sigaction (SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
```

I tried to write another thing different to `NULL` but it doesn't work. Why `NULL`? What is the meaning of that `NULL` in `sigaction`?

PS: it works as I want tho

Comment: [man 2 sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)

Comment: I already read this same web page but I still don't understand...

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? The man page says verbatim "If oldact is non-NULL, the previous action is saved in
       oldact." To me, there is nothing there *not* to understand, but if you do anyway, tell us what precisely it is.

Comment: Please, exactly what "*doesn't work*"?

Comment: OT: Among many other functions it is not save to call `printf()` from a signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of sigaction is:

`int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,
                     struct sigaction *oldact);`

The old action, that is the one you are replacing, is written to the pointer in the third argument. If you don't need this result, you can provide NULL to ignore it.

> If oldact is non-NULL, the previous action is saved in oldact.

Getting the old action is usefull to temporarily replace it.

For example, modify your code like this:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sigint_count = 0;
...
    struct sigaction backup;
    sigaction (SIGINT, &sa, &backup);
    while(sigint_count < 10) {}
    sigaction (SIGINT, &backup, NULL);
    printf("^C again will terminate me.\n");
    while(1){}
```

declare the `sig_atomic_t` variable as `volatile` if it is accessed from concurrent contexts. If you don't, the compiler might "cache" the value in a register and the `while(<)` is endless